# I am trying to draw a circle with coordinate plane using loops in C programming but ıt does not give me the lower part of circle

Tags: c

As you see on the image there are no * in lower part of the circle. Why is that?

Equations in the loops: y = 10 - i   ,   x  = j-10   or  k-10

Circle formula =  r^2 = (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2

```
    int i, j, k;
    
        for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
            if (i == 10) {
                for (j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
                    if (pow(r * r - (j -10 -a)*(j -10 -a), 0.5) + b == 0) {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else if (j == 10) {
                        printf("|");
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("-");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (k = 0; k < 21; k++) {
                    if (pow(r * r - (k -10 -a)*(k -10 -a), 0.5) + b == 10 - i) {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else if (k == 10) {
                        printf("|");
                    }
                    else {
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaCyU.jpg)

Comment: Read https://floating-point-gui.de/ and  [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) - using `==` on `float` or `double` usually does not work

Comment: Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)...) ... and debugger (e.g [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Take inspiration from existing open source projects (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or others on https://github.com/ ...). See [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: it may be better if you include a complete program that's compilable by `gcc`... instead of people reading it having to add things to it to test your program. That's especially true for `r`, `a`, `b` all not having any definition (except in your screenshot)

Comment: For your next question, please provide some [mre] (with a `main`) and show what you observed at compile time and at runtime

Comment: Don't forget that the square root has **two** solutions: ±√x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You program should be more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k;
    int a = 3, b = 4, r = 5;
    int x, y;
    
        for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
            y = -(i - 10);

            if (y == 0) {
                for (j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
                    x = j - 10;

                    if (r * r == pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2)) {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else if (x == 0) {
                        printf("|");
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("-");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (k = 0; k < 21; k++) {
                    x = k - 10;

                    if (r * r == pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2)) {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else if (x == 0) {
                        printf("|");
                    }
                    else {
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

}
```

When you match your equation, you should allow for (-3) ^ 2 is 9, while if you take the square root of `9`, you could only match a 3, unless if you also check whether the "minus" of the square root is a 3, which is troublesome.

It might also be good that if you use `x` and `y` and do the calculations, and then at the last moment, map to the screen's method of displaying it, or a similar way, instead of using `i` and then `-(i - 10)` or `10 - i` every where to mean `y`, so I added the `x` and `y` in your program.  You might also comment that `(a, b)` is supposed to be the center of the circle.

[image]

There is also one point about, it seems the difference between `y` being `0` or not is that you print out the hyphen (for the x-axis), vs a space, so your program could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i, j;
    int a = 3, b = 4, r = 5;
    int x, y;

    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        y = -(i - 10);

        for (j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
            x = j - 10;

            if (r * r == pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2)) {
                printf("*");
            }
            else if (x == 0) {
                printf("|");
            }
            else {
                printf(y == 0 ? "-" : " ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");    
    }
}
```

and in fact, you don't need `i` and `j`, but can directly iterate through `x` and `y`, as your way of displaying is only one character each time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 4, r = 5;
    int x, y;

    for (y = 10; y >= -10; y--) {

        for (x = -10; x <= 10; x++) {
            if (r * r == pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2)) {
                printf("*");
            }
            else if (x == 0) {
                printf("|");
            }
            else {
                printf(y == 0 ? "-" : " ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");    
        
    }
}
```